# Ultrasonic sensor as counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to code ultrasonic sensors to count the number of cars in a parking lot. I am relatively new to Python, so I am asking here for help.

I have three parking slots, in which each of them has an ultrasonic sensor.

How do I make it so that the sensors and their counters work together? For example, when the parking slots are empty, the counter shows three parking slots available. When two parking slots are filled, the counter shows one availability, etc.

I have done the following code, and I am wondering how I could continue to achieve my objective?

```py
# Sensor 1
def distance_1():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(TRIG_1, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG_1, False)

    print("Reading Sensor 1")

    while GPIO.input(ECHO_1) == 0:
        start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO_1) == 1:
        end = time.time()

    duration = end - start
    sound = 34000 / 2
    distance = duration * sound
    round(distance, 0)

    total = 3
    count = total

    if distance <= 10:
        count -= 1
    elif distance > 10:
        count += 1

    if count < 0:
        count = 0
    elif count > total:
        count = total

    print(count)
    mylcd.lcd_display_string("{}".format(count), 2)

# Sensor 2
def distance_2():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(TRIG_2, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG_2, False)

    print("Reading Sensor 2")

    while GPIO.input(ECHO_2) == 0:
        start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO_2) == 1:
        end = time.time()

    duration = end - start
    sound = 34000 / 2
    distance = duration * sound
    round(distance, 0)

    total = 3
    count = total

    if distance <= 10:
        count -= 1
    elif distance > 10:
        count += 1

    if count < 0:
        count = 0
    elif count > total:
        count = total

    print(count)
    mylcd.lcd_display_string("{}".format(count), 2)

# Sensor 3
def distance_3():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(TRIG_3, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG_3, False)

    print("Reading Sensor 3")

    while GPIO.input(ECHO_3) == 0:
        start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO_3) == 1:
        end = time.time()

    duration = end - start
    sound = 34000 / 2
    distance = duration * sound
    round(distance, 0)

    total = 3
    count = total

    if distance <= 10:
        count -= 1
    elif distance > 10:
        count += 1

    if count < 0:
        count = 0
    elif count > total:
        count = total

    print(count)
    mylcd.lcd_display_string("{}".format(count), 2)


while True:
    distance_1()
    distance_2()
    distance_3()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate Can I ask what the two sensors are for? One for entering and one for leaving?

Comment: I find it hard to do with only one sensor. I guess that a better solution could be to use one sensor (every kind of sensor: you can use ultrasonic or infrared for example) for each parking slot. Connecting every sensor to you raspberry, and manage the incoming signals from there. For these small applications, I prefear to use raspberry pi zero, it's a cheaper solution, including connectivity hardware (bluetooth and wifi).

Comment: @MarteValerioFalcone I've tried using three sensors for three parking slots, but couldn't get the results I wanted. The code is similar to the one above, just with three functions for the three sensors. How would I make it so that the sensors work together to show on the counter? I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: It's hard without seeing the code, can you post the code by editing the question? Another suggestion: in python, indentation means! You should indent the statement of a function when you define it. Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

Comment: @MarteValerioFalcone I've edited the code! How do I make the counters for the three sensors to work together? I just don't know how to continue from there. And thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with programming is there are so many ways to achieve the same result.

Looking at your code, I would suggest taking a step back and refactoring it to use Python classes instead. You have a lot of code repetition happening, and eventually, the code will break if you need to keep adding more sensors.

For example:

```py
class Parking:
    "This is a parking class"

    def __init__(self, space):
        self.space = space

    def empty(self):
        if self.space == 0:
            print('Parking space is empty')

    def full(self):
        if self.space == 1:
            print('Parking space is full')

    def distance(self):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.output(TRIG, True)

        . . . 


# Input:
sensor1 = Parking(1)
sensor2 = Parking(1)
sensor3 = Parking(0)

# Output:
sensor1.empty()
sensor2.empty()
sensor3.empty()

# Output:
sensor1.full()
sensor2.full()
sensor3.full()
```

You can then update a dictionary with the output to monitor the latest sensor information. Ideally, the dictionary would be written to a central file accessible by all the sensors or raspberry pis to read.

```py
available_spaces = {"sensor1": 0, "sensor2": 1, "sensor3": 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed your code and I did some refactorings.

I suggest you to use constant values initialization (the config section you see in the code below). The values I used are random.

A function can be parametrized, so you can pass arguments to functions, and avoid writing the same piece of code changing only a few values in the same place.

You should set up your microcontroller when the script starts, to tell the board how you are using the pins (as input or output).

I didn't dig into on the snippet above the lcd_display_string and why are you doing those operations. I suppose that these are required to print on screen the distance.

```
## configuration
# trigger
TRIG_1 = 17
TRIG_2 = 27
TRIG_3 = 22

# echo
ECHO_1 = 10
ECHO_2 = 9
ECHO_3 = 11

# timings
INITIAL_DELAY = 0.5
TRIGGERING_DELAY = 0.00001


## support functions
# initializing GPIO
def set_up():
    # set trigger GPIOs as output pins
    GPIO.setup(TRIG_1, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(TRIG_2, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(TRIG_3, GPIO.OUT)
    
    # set echo GPIOs as input pins
    GPIO.setup(ECHO_1, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(ECHO_2, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(ECHO_3, GPIO.IN)

# I didn't dig into these values and why are you doing these operations. I suppose that these are required to print on screen the distance.
def print_distance_on_lcd(distance):
    total = 3
    count = total

    if distance <= 10:
        count -= 1
    elif distance > 10:
        count += 1

    if count < 0:
        count = 0
    elif count > total:
        count = total

    print(count)
    mylcd.lcd_display_string("{}".format(count), 2)


def trigger(trigger):
    time.sleep(INITIAL_DELAY)
    GPIO.output(trigger, True)      # set output pin on HIGH state
    time.sleep(TRIGGERING_DELAY)
    GPIO.output(trigger, False)     # set output pin on LOW state


def distance(t, echo):
    trigger(t)
    
    # initializing the variables here, allows you to use it outside the while block below
    # using variable names that explains their content
    start_time = time.time()
    end_time = time.time()

    # this block is not wrong, but unnecessary: initializing the variable like above is enough
    '''
    while GPIO.input(echo) == 0:
        start_time = time.time()
    '''

    while GPIO.input(echo) == 1:
        end_time = time.time()

    duration = end_time - start_time
    
    sound = 34000 / 2
    distance = duration * sound

    return distance


# call initialization function (this will be executed only one time)
set_up()

# loop forever
while True:
    set_up()

    print("Reading Sensor 1")
    distance_sensor_1 = distance(TRIG_1, ECHO_1)
    print_distance_on_lcd(distance_sensor_1)
    
    print("Reading Sensor 2")
    distance_sensor_2 = distance(TRIG_2, ECHO_2)
    print_distance_on_lcd(distance_sensor_2)
    
    print("Reading Sensor 3")
    distance_sensor_3 = distance(TRIG_3, ECHO_3)
    print_distance_on_lcd(distance_sensor_3)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error, do you know what might be the problem? trigger(trigger)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Try deleting the line `distance = round(distance, 0)`

Comment: I did, and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: I noticed right now that you edited the comment adding 'trigger(trigger)'. Change `def distance(trigger, echo):` in `def distance(t, echo):` and `trigger(trigger)` in `trigger(t)`

Comment: I got the code to run, thank you! But the counter stays at 2 and doesn't change when I put objects near my sensors. Do you think it might have to do with the counter part of my code? Or is it not reading my sensors?

Comment: You're welcome! Just try to insert a `print(distance)` line inside the `trigger(t, echo)` function and post the result

Comment: I'm assuming you meant the `def distance(t, echo):` function. I got zero output from all the sensors, but when I removed the quotes from `while GPIO.input(echo) == 0: start_time = time.time()` I managed to get the values from the sensors. However, this time the counter kept decrementing and incrementing repeatedly when I put an object near my sensor, so I think the problem might be the counter code in the `def print_distance_on_lcd(distance):` function.